# How to 301 redirect from one language to default language

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, prestashop-1.6

I´ve set up a prestashop and have activated two languages Danish and English. The English version will not be used for a while, but I want search engines to cache the domain.com/webshop/da/ from the beginning. I didn´t know how to add the /da/ with .htaccess.

The problem is that even if robots.txt exclude the /en/ peoples browser language (en) will put prestashop into /en/.

I would like to redirect the domain.dk/webshop/en/[products] to domain.dk/webshop/da/[products]
So customers do not land on the English version that is not translated.

How can I do that?

Or do you see a better solution for me?
Have a nice day. Best T

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to redirect the domain.dk/webshop/en/[products] to domain.dk/webshop/da/[products]

You can use this rule as your very first rule in `/webshop/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /da/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.